# Nuxt Speedkit breaks Lighthouse Chrome extension

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, lighthouse

I installed the latest version of Nuxt Speedkit (2.2.8) in my Nuxt 3 project with the hope of improving my Lighthouse score (using the Lighthouse Chrome Developers tools extension). However, Nuxt Speedkit breaks Lighthouse. I get this error after running a Lighthouse audit:

```
"There were issues affecting this run of Lighthouse:

The page did not paint any content. Please ensure you keep the browser window in the foreground during the load and try again. (NO_FCP)"
```

I can see during the test that the web page is blank (though it normally loads fine in the browser). When I disable the Nuxt Speedkit module (or disable the `speedkit.detection.performance` option in `nuxt.config`, Lighthouse works as expected. How do I make Nuxt Speedkit play nicely with Lighthouse?